# Parallelizing a h5 conversion to parquet

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

I have a set of 1500 .H5 files that I have to process and convert to parquet. So far I've created a function that:

- Reads a H5 file to pandas dataframe
- Converts it to a spark dataframe w/ `spark.createDataFrame(df)`
- Makes the necessary treatments
- Saves it to parquet

But so far I could only apply this function in sequential. When I try to use `sc.parallelize()`, it gives an error (for what I could gather, the problem lies within the conversion `spark.createDataFrame(df)` inside).

What should be the best approach to this? I'm using databricks btw.

Comment: Maybe https://www.slideshare.net/databricks/continuous-application-with-fair-scheduler-with-robert-xue (slides 3-10) could help...

Comment: Thanks! This will help me a lot too!